# An experience or experience?

Tags: articles

Which one is correct and why? Or if both are correct, what's the difference?

> Learning is an experience.
>
> Learning is experience.

Answer (score 1):

If you have *experience* of something, you have spent time doing that job or being in that situation, and probably know how to do the job or cope with the situation.

> I have had five years' experience as a hairdresser.
>
> I have had experience of being in hospital for long periods.

*An experience* is a single instance of something happening to you.

> Riding behind my brother on his motorbike is an experience I don't want to repeat!

You must decide for yourself which sense you want to express in your sentence.

Comment: Before I can want to choose one or the other I need to know what each of them means. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: I think that both sentences make sense.

Answer (score -1):

"Learning is an experience." is the correct one. Experience is the noun in this sentence.

You can also use 'experience' as a substitute for 'I have a skill in this certain area'.

An example for using 'experience' as a substitute for 'I have some skill in this certain area'.:

> A: Do you know how to ski?

> B: I have some experience skiing while I was in high school

Comment: _Experience_ isn't necessarily the same as _skill_.

Comment: Why is "Learning is experience" wrong?